# Thunderbird Message List Pane Size

Tags: thunderbird, list

Is there a way to reduce the number of messages listed in the Message List pane?  I can drag the bottom of it down and increase the number shown, but if I drag it up, the least number I can display is like 10 messages, which eats up lots of view space, especially with the horrendous size of the message headers in the Message pane below!  Alternatively, (or in addition,) can I somehow reduce the size of the message header?  I have a rather wide screen, but I use the whole top of it up with lots of extraneous messages in the list!)

Comment: I found the answer to this and a bunch more fixes to the stuff that got messed up with the latest version of Thunderbird!
Check out https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1423733 for this question, and also
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/user/Toad-Hall/questions
for a bunch of his answers to other stuff that got messed up!
Go Toad Hall!